# Null check error in flutter in flutter inday

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

How to fix the null check error because I use  `!` that create the error.

```
void initialGetSaved() async{
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    
    // Read the data, decode it and store it in map structure
    Map<String,dynamic> jsondatais = jsonDecode(sharedPreferences.getString('userData')!); // The error starts here 
    var data = UserData.fromJson(jsondatais);
    if(jsondatais.isNotEmpty){
      gender = '';
      birthdate;
      height = '';
      weight = '';
      goal = '';
      workout_per_week = '';
      how_many_weeks = '';
      meal_plan = '';
      meal_category = '';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Null check error means you used `!` on a null variable, in this case it means
sharedPreferences did not have any string `'userData'`, there are many ways to fix this, and it is hard for me to tell you which to use if I don't understand the use case, but hopefully this will solve the error:

from

```
sharedPreferences.getString('userData')!
```

to

```
sharedPreferences.getString('userData') ?? '{}'
```

which will ensure you always have a non null value.